# When did Lisp start using symbols for arithmetic?

Tags: history, lisp

Looking through the August 1979 issue of Byte magazine, it discusses a dialect of Lisp in which arithmetic operations are denoted by words like PLUS and TIMES.

Later dialects like Common Lisp and Scheme use the symbols common to other languages like `+` and `*`.

When did Lisp generally switch from one convention to the other?

Comment: Are you able to give more information about the dialect of Lisp you were just reading about?

Comment: @Wilson It doesn't seem to say what the dialect is specifically called, or if it does, I missed it. The Byte issue can be downloaded in PDF if you want to take a look yourself.

Comment: Scheme is actually earlier than 1979. Scheme was first described in 1975 and had already + and *.

Comment: If you could [edit] your question to give us the article title and page number (the issue is full of articles about various LISPs) that would be very helpful. You'd get bonus points for also giving a link to the page in that issue, [like this](https://archive.org/details/BYTE_Vol_04-08_1979-08_Lisp/page/n4), so that others can simply click it rather than paging through the issue themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the various [LISP 1.5](http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~rountev.1/6341/pdf/Manual.pdf) systems (on the IBM 7090 and
otherwise) appears always to have used only `PLUS`, `DIFFERENCE`,
`MINUS` (unary), etc. (§4.2 p.25) Its small derivative [PDP-1
LISP](https://www.computerhistory.org/pdp-1/_media/pdf/DEC.pdp_1.1964.102650371.pdf) (1964) also did as well (§2 p.3 Table 1, though I don't
know what happened to `DIFFERENCE`.)

[LISP 2](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/lisp2/TM-2260_002_00-Internal_Language.pdf), discussed extensively in the early '60s but never
implemented, did use symbols for arithmetic in the ALGOL-like "source
language," but I think you're not talking about this. The S-expression
"internal language" still used `PLUS` etc. (See example of both in
§5.2 on p.13.)

The BBN descendent, [INTERLISP](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_xeroxinterfMan_35779510/page/n247) (also started on the PDP-1, but
eventually moving to the PDP-10 amongst many other machines) was still
using `plus` etc. in 1974, and had added `iplus` and friends to do
faster integer arithmetic that avoided boxing the values where
possible. (§13.1 p.13.2) This continued on through [at least
1983](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_xeroxinternceManualOct1983_52302609/page/n71). (§2.9.4 p.2.44)

The other direct descendant, Maclisp, through [at least 1970](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/MIT/AIM-190-White-Interim_LISP_Users_Guide.pdf)
was the same, as far as names of numerical functions go. (No list of
functions in this one, but see code on pp. 14, 20, 25, and 30.)

#### The Start of Symbols

However, [by 1973](https://www.saildart.org/MACLSP.DBA%5BUP,DOC%5D), as well as using `'A` as a shorter form
of `(QUOTE A)` (which I think was first introduced in [CONNIVER](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6203) in 1972),
Maclisp started using symbols for arithmetic functions. (§7.1.4). (This seems
to have been part of the changes made during Moon's project to
reimplement Maclisp on the Honeywell 6180 running MULTICS.) However,
these were used for type-specific versions of the
functions; `plus` etc. was still used for the generic versions. Here I
quote from the [published manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_A._Moon) of 1974 because it's much
easier to read.

Section 7 "Functions on Numbers" covers the numerical operations.
From §7.2 "Comparison":

> - `=`         SUBR 2 args
>
>   (= *x* *y*) is `t` if *x* and *y* are numerical equal. *x* and *y*
>     must be both fixnums or both flonums.
>
> ...
>
> - `greaterp`         LSUBR 2 or more args
>
>   `greaterp` compares its arguments, which must be numbers, from
>     left to right. If any argument is not greater than the next,
>     `greaterp` returns `nil`. But if the arguments to `greaterp` are
>     strictly decreasing, the reault is `t`.
> - `>`         SUBR 2 args
>
>   (> *x* *y*) is `t` if *x* is strictly greater than *y* and `nil`
>     otherwise. *x* and *y* must be both fixnums or both flonums.

And from §7.4 "Arithmetic":

> - `plus`         LSUBR 0 or more args
>
>   `plus` returns the sum of its arguments, which may be any kind of
>     numbers. Conversions to flonum or bignum representation are done
>     as needed. Flonum representation will be used if any of the
>     arguments are flonums; otherwise fixnum representation will be
>     used if the results can fit in fixnum form. If it cannot, bugnum
>     representation will be used.
> - `+`         LSUBR 0 or more args
>
>   `+` returns the sum of its arguments. The arguments must be
>     fixnums, and the result is always a fixnum. Overflow is ignored.

#### Symbols Replace Words

The original paper on Scheme, AIM-349 ["Scheme: An Interpreter for the
Extended Lambda Calculus"](https://web.archive.org/web/20171201033214/http://repository.readscheme.org/ftp/papers/ai-lab-pubs/AIM-349.pdf) (Sussman and Steele, December 1975)¹,
uses symbols such as `=` and `+` for the `EQUAL` and `PLUS` functions,
as you can immediately see from the first example in section 2, and
there's no a mention of the word versions. This seems to be the first
time that these were used for generic, rather than integer
type-specific, functions and replaced, rather than augmenting, the
word functions. This is not formally defined, however, nor
is it in AIM-452 [R¹RS](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/6283). It's not until 1985, with the publication of
AIM-848 [R²RS](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/5600) (§II.6 p.39) that the numerical operations are
specifically defined to be `+`, `-`, etc. and by that time of course
Common LISP had already done this too.

If you want to dig around yourself for more information or try to find
earlier examples, a good source of documentation for many, many
versions of LISP is the Software Preservation Group's [History of
LISP](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP) page.

---

¹This is the first "Lambda Paper", and might also retroactively
be called "R⁰RS."

Answer (score 15):

Lisp is not a single language, but a whole ecosystem of different languages. Moreover, there's no standard covering all Lisps, like with C or Fortran, so for this reason, `+` and `plus` are equally "valid".

When [Lisp 1 (March 1960)](https://web.archive.org/web/20100717111134/http://history.siam.org/sup/Fox_1960_LISP.pdf) was written, the primitive operations defined were `car`, `cdr`, `cons`, `and`, `or`, `cond`, etc. The arithmetic operations were not primitives at that time, so the programmers chose their own names.

At least [Lisp 1.5](http://www.dbit.com/pub/pdp8/nickel/langs/lisp/ascii/polprl.li) (early 60s) had both.

But [this Lisp from 1970](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/decus/pdp8/8-341_LISP-8.pdf) had `PLUS` and `MINUS` but no `+` nor `-`.

If you consider Scheme (1975) to be a Lisp, then it is a specimen having both `+` and `&+` (the latter is an optimisation for two arguments only).

And Common Lisp (1984) has `+` but not `plus` as you have noted.

So I posit that we gradually settled on `+`-style symbols starting in the 70s, and the situation was a state of flux before then, for the reason that arithmetic operations were not even primitive operations to begin with.

Comment: Common Lisp _does_ have a standard; in fact it was the first object-oriented language to get an ANSI standard.

Comment: @sds, That's right, but there's no standard that covers *everything* that I'd personally call Lisp.

Comment: The way I read the LISP 1.0 doc, the arithmetic functions have to have alphanumeric names, since they're atoms, and atoms have names that are alphanumeric.

Comment: @another-dave yes, but that could have been `PLUS` or `ADD` or `QUXHJFNL`, anything you like.

Comment: Agree; but I meant "+ was not possible" rather than "PLUS is the only possibility".

Comment: The Lisp I manual specified the functions SUM and PRDCT for float operations. It provides PLUS and TIMES for use in symbolic algebraic expressions. See the function SMPLFY.